# Stream data from cassandra

Tags: cassandra, mapreduce, nosql

Is there any way to stream all data from cassandra database?

I am using node.js and [node-cassandra-cql](https://github.com/jorgebay/node-cassandra-cql) driver and there is stream method but it is working in way that first fetches all data and then fires callback function for each row which actually means that it doesn't stream but just emulate streaming and usually I get Operation timed out if I have lots of data (1 000 000 rows).

Does cassandra by itself support some kind of doing this or I have to use map-reduce and all those hadoop stuff?

Comment: have you resolved this? I have the same question.